# Apache and all other services are running but Website is not reachable

Tags: wordpress, apache, ubuntu-18.04

I have one WordPress website hosted on Ubuntu 18 VPS. Since couple of days, website gets unreachable even though Apache, Database and other necessary services are running. I checked all logs but there is nothing in it. Memory and CPU utilisation is below 50%. Apache service restart solves the issue. Can anyone know where exactly issue is?

Comment: go to `/var/log/apache2/error.log` and let us know what kind of error does it report. Seems to be like memory leak, error log could provide more details.

Comment: It says maxchildrequest exceed error however, the error occurrence and website down are not related. for example, website was down on Sunday 11 AM but error was occurred in the morning 8 AM. There are not any other errors

Comment: is it an old site with many posts and custom theme or a new experimental site ?